# Story about a child communicating with a computer

Tags: story-identification, novel

I cannot for the life of me remember what this novel was called, all I can remember is having the book with no cover and was a light blue-ish hardcover book (not that, that helps any I'm sure)

I believe the main character was a girl (or not, but definitely a kid) that communicated with a computer, and the computer drew pictures - I remember seeing a picture made up of little x's in the novel. I believe the computer belonged to her father as well, but I'm not 100% sure on that part.

I can't remember the name of any of the characters.

Comment: Welcome! If you can, please clarify (rephrase) the first paragraph. Also, any additional information (e. g. language, year) would be of help.

Comment: It's not much to go on. I doubt we will find it.

Comment: I'm not surprised as I can just barely remember what happens in the book, but it's been bugging me for such a long time now. I'm not sure what year it was published, but I know I read it in the late 90's early 2000's, and it was in English. I've searched and found various novels about computers but none of them turned out to be the one I was looking for. I feel as if I've imagined it all my life now.

Comment: Long shot, but could it be _Contact_ by Carl Sagan? Story follows Elly (a girl) from childhood to adulthood; her relationship with her father is explored, and there's a computer in the end that draws something on screen (Namely *pi* in base 11).

Comment: Well, a picture made of little x’s is enough to go on for someone who read the book. Can you remember any other details, though?

Comment: The Diamond Age by Neal Stephenson, perhaps?

Comment: Contact and The Diamond Age are two books I came across while searching, and it was neither of those ones. It's annoying as I can't even picture the cover of the book to give more details, as it didn't even have the sleeve so it was just a plain blue hardback book that I must have got from a garage sale or something. I'm wracking my brain trying to remember more details which would actually be more helpful in identifying the book.

Comment: Do you happen to recall what the pictures depicted? Any personality traits of the protagonist? Did her father build the computer?